# curve_fit: calculations with x before fit

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using the curve_fit function of the scipy package to fit some experimental data. I wrote my objective function like that:

```
def binding21(G0, eps1, eps2, K1, K2):

    A = K1 * K2
    B = K1 * (2 * K2 * H0 - K2 * G0 + 1)
    C = K1 * (H0 - G0) + 1
    D = G0

    roots = np.roots([A, B, C, -D])
    roots = [value for value in roots if np.isreal(value)]
    G = max(roots)

    y = (eps1 * H0 * K1 * G + eps2 * H0 * K1 * K2 * G**2) / \
        (1 + K1 * G + K1 * K2 * G**2)

    return y
```

G0 is my array of x values. However, the model I use in my objective function is not defined as y=f(G0), but instead as y=f(G=f(G0)).

I need to find the roots of G=f(G0) before I can calculate y: I have to choose the smallest positive value of the roots returned, and assign it to G.

For now, the previous code returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djipey/Working/Data_boss/21.py", line 80, in <module>
    result = mod.fit(y, G0=x)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lmfit/model.py", line 506, in fit
    output.fit(data=data, weights=weights)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lmfit/model.py", line 710, in fit
    self.init_fit    = self.model.eval(params=self.params, **self.userkws)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lmfit/model.py", line 372, in eval
    result = self.func(**self.make_funcargs(params, kwargs))
  File "/home/djipey/Working/Data_boss/21.py", line 38, in binding21
    roots = np.roots([A, B, C, -D])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 207, in roots
    p = atleast_1d(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 50, in atleast_1d
    ary = asanyarray(ary)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 525, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Because I'm trying to find the roots using G0, that is not a single value but an array.

Could you help me to solve this problem ?

EDIT:

I'm basically trying to fit this equation:
[image: equation]

With:

[image: explanation]

Epsilon_HG, Epsilon_HG2, K1 and K2 are the parameters. H0 is a known constant. G is the variable in this model. And G depends on G0, which is the "x" values I give to the model.

I have several experimental data points where Y=f(G0). But I need to fit Y=f(G). G can be obtained only by solving the cubic equation above.

Comment: Which of the lines throws the exception?

Comment: I added the full traceback.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to compute but the error is clear when refering to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) of numpy.roots. It calculates the roots of a polynomial which coefficients are given as a an _array_like_ for example a list of scalars. You use a list with 3 scalars and an array. How dow you want the polynomial to look like? Are all elements in `G0` coefficients of a polynomial?

Comment: I added the equations I'm trying to solve/fit. Basically, what I would need: access the particular values of G0 when the Y function is evaluated.

Comment: Could you add the data you are using?!

Comment: @Rififi With your answer I sort of understand what you wanted. You asked for "y=f(G=f(G0))" but you wanted "y=f(G=h(G0))" where h is a function that computes "list of biggest roots of polynomials with G0 in the parameters". Maybe you can edit that part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, which is in fact very simple:

```
G = []


def binding21(G0, eps1, eps2, K1, K2):

    global G

    G = []

    for value in G0:
        A = K1 * K2
        B = K1 * (2 * K2 * H0 - K2 * value + 1)
        C = K1 * (H0 - value) + 1
        D = value

        roots = np.roots([A, B, C, -D])

        roots = [float(value) for value in roots if np.isreal(value)]

        G.append(max(roots))

    G = np.array(G)

    y = (eps1 * H0 * K1 * G + eps2 * H0 * K1 * K2 * G**2) / \
        (1 + K1 * G + K1 * K2 * G**2)

    return y
```

I basically re-calculate G at each iteration of curve_fit. But I have to do it for the whole list, I can't use one particular value. So, I just do it for the entire list :)

And as I need the final value of G, I had to use a global variable. I know it's evil, but I couldn't find a better solution in that case.

For the chemists out there, this snippet is used to fit titrations for binding experiments (model 1:2).

Comment: I don't like using globals either so what I would do is outsource the computation of G into another function `def calcG(G0, K1, K2, H0):...`. After the optimization you can than call that function again to obtain `G`. Another approach would be to wrap your code into a class with `G` as a member.

Comment: True. I'll go for one of these solutions if my script grows bigger. For now, globals are not *that* evil.